# Automatically zoom out browser as per user resolution

Tags: javascript, zooming

I have run into a big problem ... 
I have designed my site at 1920 X 1080 ... It looks great on 1920 X 1080 ... 
Then after designing the entire site ... 
I ran into a major design flaw, I should have thought of earlier .. 
I realized majority of my target audience uses 1280 or 1024 kind of resolutions ... and don`t run latest versions of browsers .. 
What do I do now ???

I tried using javascript and zoom css property but it only works on chrome,safari.. They  handle it exceptionally and IE 9 messes it up a little ... But firefox makes a mess ...

Please help me ... Heres my site

http://www.unitedtraders.biz

Thank you ...

Comment: If the funds allow it, I would hire a designer to do the job. Or use a free template because to be honest (not trying to hurt you, just honest opinion) it still looks awful in chrome. Programmers aren't designers and vice versa.

Comment: Site screams 1999. Flash animation does nothing, and that little marquee on the left is useless.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [CSS3 Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). They allow you to include stylesheets depending on the browser's viewport's size.

Answer (score 0):

I would include different CSS sheets for every resolution, as it's a fixed website. 
Since there are a lot of small details that need to be attended, just zooming out the website wouldn't keep it pretty on any resolution.